# json data don't load when i call with getjson

Tags: javascript, json

i'm drawing a chart with json data
my controller return json data

```
http://localhost:50418/json/index return
```

json

```
[{"ID":1,"name":"bob","score":212},{"ID":2,"name":"alice","score":150}]
```

in my view  i tried this it worked so the problem isn't with the chart

```
var data = [],

    json = [{ "ID": 1, "name": "bob", "score": 212 }, { "ID": 2, "name": "alice", "score": 150 }];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    data.push({
        name: json[i].name,
        id: json[i].ID,
        y: json[i].score
    });
}
```

but when i do this it doesn't work to get the data from the controller

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:50418/json/index", function(response){
       json = response;
  });
```

how to get the data from the controller to the variable json???

Comment: Open Chrome Developer Tools, then in the Sources tab find your script and put a breakpoint inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you got to put all your code in the callback right?

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:50418/json/index", function(response){
    json = response;
    var data = [],
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        data.push({
            name: json[i].name,
            id: json[i].ID,
            y: json[i].score
        });
    }
});

// over here, json is undefined
// stuff here is executed before the getJSON actually gets the response...
```